# Yup schema validation with regex keeps giving me field errors

Tags: react-native, yup

So I have a problem with my yup validation. I want to make sure that for my name field the user can enter only letters or spaces. However no matter what I type in my field it keeps telling me it is incorrect.

```
const letterRegex = new RegExp("/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/");

const pg_BinnenCoLoondienst: yup.SchemaOf<RowBinnenCoLoonDienstData> = yup
  .object()
  .shape({
    REV_PE_BCL_Naam: yup.string().required("Name is required").matches(letterRegex, "Name can only contain letters & spacces"),
```

If I remove the matches part and only use required than it works perfectly so the issue is with the 'matches' part of the validation.

[image: result]

Anyone sees what I'm doing wrong?
Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex

`const letterRegex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z ]*$");`

Comment: Don't forget to trim the strings. This regex will accept spaces in start and end.